# Node field value SUM

Tags: views, entities, taxonomy-terms

is it possible to sum field values and then show in one row, instead of column sum at footer over each page.
field collection values `values1[2,3]`, `values2[43,32]`, and `values3[2]`
over the view with aggregation sum function its give me `SUM-values1[5]`, `SUM-values2[75]`, and `SUM-values3[2]` (Total: 82).

I need to just show the result 'Total' parts even values may be 1000 or more but here how we can display only the whole sum value excluding list down values at top?

[image]

Comment: In Fields try adding and using the `Global: Math expression` not sure if it will help you, but worth the try.